# How to configure the spring-servlet.xml to correct the Injection failure on the Spring-MVC 3.0 project?

Tags: spring-mvc, code-injection, autowired

I am working on a Spring MVC 3.0 project and have just used @Autowired in my code, but I got the below error message on the Console window:

```
严重: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.maskkk.service.UserService com.maskkk.controller.LoginController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.maskkk.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The logincontroller is to check people to login into the website.
Below is its code:

```
package com.maskkk.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.maskkk.model.Login;

import com.maskkk.model.User;

import com.maskkk.service.UserService;

@Controller

public class LoginController {

 @Autowired

UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)

 public ModelAndView showLogin(HttpServletRequest request, 
 HttpServletResponse response) {

ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");

mav.addObject("login", new Login());

return mav;

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/loginProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public ModelAndView loginProcess(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response,
@ModelAttribute("login") Login login) {

 ModelAndView mav = null;

 User user = userService.validateUser(login);

 if (null != user) {

 mav = new ModelAndView("welcome");

 mav.addObject("firstname", user.getFirstname());

 } else {

 mav = new ModelAndView("login");

 mav.addObject("message", "Username or Password is wrong!!");

 }

 return mav;

 }

 }
```

Since:

```
@Autowired

UserService userService;
```

The userservice is below:

```
package com.maskkk.service;

import com.maskkk.model.Login;
import com.maskkk.model.User;

public interface UserService {

   void register(User user);

   User validateUser(Login login);
}
```

My project structure is like above:
[image]

And my spring-servlet.xml is below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">  

 <!-- 下面是配置扫描包的位置,包名为com.maskkk,也就是说,我们的试图解析器应该放在 
 com.maskkk包下. -->
 <!-- import resource="classpath:com/config/user-beans.xml" /> -->

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.maskkk.*" />
 <context:annotation-config />
 <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.maskkk.*" />  --> 
 <!-- 自动扫描(自动注入) -->
 <!-- <context:component-scan base- 
 package="com.maskkk.controller.LoginController" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.maskkk.service.UserService" /> -->

 <mvc:resources mapping="/image/**" location="/image/" />
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation
 .AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation
 .DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
 <bean id="viewResolver"  
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <!-- 前缀,我们的视图文件应该放到/WEB-INF/view/目录下,这里我们需要在WEB-INF下面 
  创建view文件夹 -->  
  <property name="prefix" value="/" />  
  <!-- 设置后缀为.jsp -->
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
  </bean>




   <bean id="messageSource" 
   class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="multipartResolver"class="org.springframework.web
   .multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">  
   <property name="maxUploadSize" value="209715200" />     
   <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />  
   <property name="resolveLazily" value="true" />  
    </bean>  
   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory
  .annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
  <bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc
  .method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">  
  </bean>  
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc
  .method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">  
   <property name="messageConverters">  
    <list>  
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json
        .MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />  
    </list>  
    </property>  
    </bean> 
    <!-- 加入json支持 -->  
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
     <!-- 处理请求response返回值，如下配置能正确返回字符串型返回值,如返回值为对 
     象，则自动转为json -->
    <bean id="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"       
     class="org.springframework.http.converter
     .json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
            <value>application/json; charset=UTF-8</value>
            <value>text/html; charset=UTF-8</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mappingStringHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />

     <bean id="handleAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc
    .annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" /><!-- json转换器 
     -->
        </list>
    </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- 设置返回字符串编码 -->  
    <bean class="org.springframework.web
   .servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
        <!--json视图拦截器，读取到@ResponseBody的时候去配置它-->
        <ref bean="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </list>
    </property>
    </bean>  

    </beans>
```

So, What is wrong with my spring-servlet.xml file? 
Any sugestions would be very helpful!

Comment: I solved this error by myself. and I show it for someone who meet the same problems. The failure of injection is because the Tomcat server did not find the beans. the error message that "No qualifying bean of type [com.maskkk.service.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}" means something was wrong in the com.maskkk.service.UserService. and this is only the interface, I lost an implementation.

Comment: So I added one UserServiceImpl.java, and also I have a resource file which declaring all the beans: "<bean id="userService" class="com.maskkk.service.UserServiceImpl" />
 
   " so I add this one to the spring-servlet.xml to import the resource and everything is Okay.

Comment: <import resource="classpath*:user-beans.xml" />